# Como modificar os campos de formulário se a entrada do usuário for inválida quando comparada com a expressão regular com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Galera, tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label>Nome<br> 
    <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]{2,30}$" autocomplete="off" title="Somente letras e acentos são permitidos. Até 30 caracteres." name="nome" maxlength="30" required autofocus/>
</label>
<label>Sobrenome<br> 
    <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]{2,40}$" autocomplete="off" title="Apenas letras, acentos e espaços são permitidos. Até 50 caracteres." name="sob" maxlength="50" required/>
</label>

...

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

E assim o formulário continua, outros campos e o botão de submit.

Queria saber como pegar o valor que o pattern retornou, para quando a entrada do usuário estiver certa nada acontecer, mas se estiver errada, mudar a cor de fundo e a borda do campo que a entrada está errada, pelo evento `change()` mesmo, sem submeter a página. Mudar os atributos CSS eu sei, mas como pegar o valor que da expressão regular não.

Estou trabalhando com JQuery mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em [browsers com o devido suporte](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid#Browser_compatibility), você resolve isso por CSS:

```css
input:invalid {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/007go6vu/

Comment: E, caso mais alguma coisa tenha que ser feita via código, basta verificar acessar a propriedade `validity.valid` dos inputs: `true` significa válido; `false`, inválido.

Comment: Legal @RuiPimentel, eu não sabia dessa.

Comment: muito legal essa, não fazia a menor ideia. O único problema é que os campos, eles iniciam após o carregamento, teoricamente invalidos, em questão de aparência não fica muito legal

Comment: @leandro17br Mas acho que isso daria pra resolver na regex, não?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que é mais ou menos isso:

```
$(':text').change(function() {
   var pattern = $('[name=nome]').attr('pattern');
   var str     = $(this).val();
   var retorno = str.match(pattern); // retorna a resposta do match...
});
```

Aí é só fazer com os outros inputs também.

Tendo o valor da variável `retorno` você pode mudar o CSS do input.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do @bfavaretto, para garantir que o formulário não acuse erro de preenchimento logo na inicialização, você pode usar outro método. Um pequeno CSS em conjunto com um Javascript+jQuery basta:

```
.invalido { background: red; color: white; }
```

Script:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    if(this.validity.valid){
        this.className = "valido";
    } else {
        this.className = "invalido";
    }
});
```

Edit: como sempre, esqueci do [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/99whoevn/).

Edit 2: para que ele acuse erro caso o formulário esteja em branco, é necessário que o atributo `required` seja declarado no `<input />`.

Comment: muito bom mesmo, vlw